# meaning of the phrase "as far as" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from [Crash Course Big History](https://youtu.be/tq6be-CZJ3w). It is 12 minute and 45 second . Here is the context:

> **As far as** we have come in the past century in crafting a history of the universe, there still many things cosmologists have yet to discover.

Besides *as far as*, I cannot get whar the first part of the sentence means. What does *come in crafting* mean?  Could you please rephrase the first part of the sentence for me.

Comment: Okay, I listened to the original sentence. Do you realize that's not exactly what he's saying? So, which sentence should we go with? Yours or his?

Comment: **as far as** here means: although.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following would be a fairly reasonable way to paraphrase your sentence:

> **With respect to how much we have been able to achieve in the past century in the history of crafting**, there are still many things cosmologists have yet to discover.

Can you understand it better now?

---

EDIT (after listening to the movie clip):

The original sentence:

> As far as we've come in the past century in crafting a history of the universe, there are still many things cosmologists have yet to discover.

Paraphrased:

> **With respect to how much we have been able to achieve in the past century in writing a history of the universe**, there are still many things cosmologists have yet to discover.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the best paraphrase to show the meaning of this would be:

> Even though we have discovered a lot about the history of the universe in the last century, there are still a lot of other things to discover.

"As far as" in this context indicates that we *have* gone very far, but it's possible to go farther.